# undefined reference to "tpl_map"

Tags: c, serialization

I would like to serialize structures.
I'm trying to use the TPL library.

I read that :

http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/userguide.html#_as_source

"build and install - as source : "

"The simplest way to use tpl is to copy the source files tpl.h and tpl.c (from the src/ directory) right into your project, and build them with the rest of your source files. No special compiler flags are required."

so, I downloaded the .zip from :
https://github.com/troydhanson/tpl

I copied "tpl.h" and "tpl.c" from the src/ directory to the directory of my "main" file

Then I added in my "main" file :

```
#include "tpl.h"

tpl_node *tn;
int id = 0;
char *name, *names[] = { "joe", "bob", "cary" };

tn = tpl_map("A(is)", &id, &name);

for(name=names[0]; id < 3; name=names[++id]) {
   tpl_pack(tn,1);
}

tpl_dump(tn, TPL_FILE, "save");
tpl_free(tn);
```

But I have the followings errors :

```
main.c: undefined reference to " tpl_map "

main.c: undefined reference to " tpl_pack "

main.c: undefined reference to " tpl_dump "

main.c: undefined reference to " tpl_free "
```

Is someone can help me please ?

Comment: This is not a programming issue, its a compiling issue: thus we would need to see your compiling command line... which should look like `gcc -o myprog main.c tpl.c ...` ... it sounds like you are leaving out the tpl.c from your compile.  It would be a good time to learn how to write a Makefile.

Comment: Your "main" file needs an actual `main()` function, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you technosaurus,

I had forgotten "tpl.c" in my "SRC" list in the makfile.

I'm new in programming, it's the first time I do this error.

Now I have 5 compiling errors,from tpl.c while I didn't touch anything like :

```
tpl.c:431:41: error: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
  'unsigned long' [-Werror,-Wsign-compare]
  ...(num_contig_fxlens >= (sizeof(contig_fxlens)/sizeof(contig_fxlens[0]))) {
```

I guess this librabry is not resulted yet, I'll try something else.

Thanks for your help.